# Image resizing tool for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, images

i have around **500 images** and i need to resize each into *6 different sizes*. Can any there scripts or software. moreover my platform is **ubuntu** .

Comment: Related: [How to easily resize images via command-line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1164/78223)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please try to use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/). First, install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then you can make a little bash script to convert them to your 6 sizes:

```
#!/bin/bash

# List all the formats you wish to have
SIZES="640x480 800x600 1024x768"

# pass directory as first argument to the script
# Use '.' (current directory) if no argument was passed
DIR=${1:-.}

find $DIR -type f | while read file; do
   for size in $SIZES; do
      # Resize and rename DSC01258.JPG into DSC01258_640x480.JPG, etc.
      # Remove the ! after $size if you do not wish to force the format
      convert -resize "${size}!" "$file" "${file%.*}_${size}.${file##*.}"
   done
done
```

Save the script as, e.g. `convert.sh`, and run:

```
chmod +x convert.sh
./convert.sh /path/to/directory # path is optional, it takes '.' as default
```

**Edit:** I edited the script to make sure to not override files when resizing, but rename them to e.g. DSC01258_640x480.JPG, and use convert instead of [`mogrify`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) since the files are actually renamed. I also sanitized the variables a bit, doesn't hurt.

I tested the script with png files and it worked fine. It should work for all kinds of image formats supported by ImageMagick:

```
$ file wave_bible_bot/*
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot1.png: PNG image, 516 x 308, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot2.png: PNG image, 515 x 428, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot3.png: PNG image, 565 x 384, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced

$ ./resize.sh wave_bible_bot/

$ file wave_bible_bot/*
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot1_1024x768.png: PNG image, 1024 x 768, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot1_640x480.png:  PNG image, 640 x 480, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot1_800x600.png:  PNG image, 800 x 600, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot1.png:          PNG image, 516 x 308, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot2_1024x768.png: PNG image, 1024 x 768, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot2_640x480.png:  PNG image, 640 x 480, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot2_800x600.png:  PNG image, 800 x 600, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot2.png:          PNG image, 515 x 428, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot3_1024x768.png: PNG image, 1024 x 768, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot3_640x480.png:  PNG image, 640 x 480, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot3_800x600.png:  PNG image, 800 x 600, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
  wave_bible_bot/wave_bible_bot3.png:          PNG image, 565 x 384, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

Answer (score 10):

If you install ImageMagick as Sathya mentioned, there is a nice GUI frontend to make resizing easier called `nautilus-image-converter`.

To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-image-converter
```

Restart nautilus (or log out and back in). It will add "Resize Images" and "Rotate Images" to your context menu as shown here:

[image]

Simply highlight all images you want to resize, right-click, select **Resize Images**, and you will get this interface:

[image]

Use the "Append" option and add a custom name to your resized images. You may want to append the size such as 1024x768 **OR** you can make 6 copies of your images in different folders, then use the **resize images in place** option on the images in each folder to overwrite them with new images that have different dimensions. **Resize images in place** will always overwrite the selected images, so be careful what you select!

Answer (score 6):

You can use ImageMagick: 
First install ImageMagick

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Next, cd to the location where your images are there:

```
cd /path/to/where/images/are/stored
```

Next, create directories according to your Imagesize

```
mkdir /path/to/where/images/are/stored/size
```

Copy the images to the directory where you wish to transform

```
cp /path/to/where/images/are/stored/* /path/to/where/images/are/stored/size
```

Next, change the directory to the other directory

```
cp /path/to/where/images/are/stored/size
```

Then, use a tool called `mogrify` provided by ImageMagick library to resize

```
mogrify -resize 640×480! *.jpg
```

This will resize all to `640*480`, `!` tells to force aspect ratio.

I don't know Bash scripting, so its not that automated.

Answer (score 2):

There really should be several references to [`mogrify` tool](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) in the `convert`'s manual. ... I searched for about forty-five minutes but it wasn't until I came across another post that I was able to start looking in the right direction.

For the benefit of others this line did exactly what I needed. It took about fifty 2meg to 3meg JPGs (in the same directory) and dropped them all down to 80 to 120 kb. And of course it left all of their names 'exactly' the same.

```
mogrify *.jpg -quality 75 -resize "640x480>" *
```

**And, again for the benefit of others:**

- `*.jpg` ... performs the mogrify command on all JPGs in the directory.
- `-quality 75` ... cuts the jpg quality down to 75% which is plenty for online viewing.
- `-resize "640x480>"` ... causes all of the images to be resized to 640x480 (notice the ">" at the end. That makes images smaller but 'not' larger. ... and don't forget the quotes; those are important.
- `*` ... and don't forget this at the very end of the command.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend phatch. Its GUI is a lot more flexible than what imagemagick and nautilus have to offer and it has a command line interface too, if you need to write a script. You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install phatch
```

Answer (score 1):

Gimp comes with batch mode. see [GIMP Batch Mode](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/).

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple to use tool: [Picture Resize](http://tabish.freeshell.org/picture-resize.html). It uses imagemagick behind the scene. When installed, it will create an icon on your linux desktop. You can drag and drop one or many images, or a folder of images on it, and it will create a resized copy of each image.
The size you want can be easily changed by right-clicking on the desktop icon.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a GUI rather than a command line tool take a look at BIR:
https://github.com/agronick/BIR

[image]